# How to click a button on website via c# on wp7

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7

I need to click a button on a website. The button in html:
 `<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Войти" />`

wp7 webBrowser do not support webBrowser.Document, so I can't use

```
foreach(HTMLElement html in webBrowser.Document.GetElementByTagName("input"))
{
 if(html.GetAttribute("value) == "Войти")
html.InvokeMember("submit");
}
```

also button has no id or tag, so I cant use "getElementsById" or "getElementsByTag"

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what you need to do. Do you need to submit a form? Against a server?

Comment: I have an url http://m.vk.com/login , i need to click a button "Войти", textboxes with email and pass i fill by      wb1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='{0}'", Login.Text));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're filling the fields using Javascript, just submit the form the same way:

```
wb1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();");
```

Comment: I tried, but it throws exception  An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.

Comment: Works, but i tried the same code and had an exception. Thanks/

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML5 Windows Phone application the default order of Browser.Navigate(...) then Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true; does not work. You need to have the Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true; before the Navigate() call.